# angular flex-layout registration issue

Tags: angular

I'm trying to install @angular/flex-layout but it doesn't seem to register corrctly.

I'm using Angular 13.0.1

in my package.json file I have:

> "@angular/flex-layout": "12.0.0-beta.38",

whilst typing this intellisence offers various versions and this is the latest.

When i go to my app.module.ts file and enter:

```
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
```

I receive the following error:

> TS2307: (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/flex-layout' or its
> corresponding type declarations.

Comment: have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and then running `npm i`, or just running `npm ci`?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I tried this but didnt make any difference

Comment: interesting. the version in my question comes up in intellisence as mentioned, but from a command line if I enter npm i @angular/flex-layout it installs "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.38",

Comment: Please, try an "npm clean" and retry an "npm i".